# Doctrine2 trying to insert instead of just referencing

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I just fetch an entity (row) from database:

```
$one = $em->getRepository()->find(1);
```

and trying to insert another entity which has foreign key with `$one`:

```
for($i=0; $i<=100; $i++) {
   $two = new TwoEntity();
   $two->setOne($one); // as you can see $one is just a foreign key. Referenced.
   $two->setSomething(true);
   $em->persist($two);

   ...
   // when each 20th cycle flush them. and clear.
   $em->flush();
   $em->clear();
}
```

**Note**: I use Doctrine2' s batch insert way. I just minimized the code for shorter explanation what im trying to do.

Instead of referencing `$one`, Doctrine trying to re-insert `$one`. It gives persist exception and if i persist `$one`, it just trying to insert `$one` over again and again. Error: `A new entity was found through the relationship...`

How can I just reference `$one` and only insert `$two` in batch?

**Update**: I tried also `$one->addTwo($two)` method on `$one` but this time errors gone but foreign key fields are empty.

## Update 2:

I did `Side Owning` and `Side Inverse` to **cascade all**. This way if i merge `$em->merge($one)` it just works. But, I don't know if this is the correct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do `$em->clear();` so `$one` is just not referenced anymore in Doctrine.

Docblock of clear method say :

```
Clears the ObjectManager. All objects that are currently managed by this ObjectManager become detached.
```

Just remove `$em->clear();` or use something like this `$em->clear('TwoEntity');`

Comment: unfortunately, it still trying to "insert"  both element and because of that it shows "duplicate" on $one. Side owning and inverse cascade all solved my problem. instead of setOne() i did addTwo on vice-versa.

Comment: Nope. You were right. I just forgot some another piece of code before that statement. clearing only that entity (`..->clear('ENTITY')`) solved my problem. All works.

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect:

```
$two->setOne($one); // as you can see $one is just a foreign key. Referenced.
```

What you need to do is something like this:

```
$two->setOne( $one->getId() );
```

Or something like that. In other words get the reference id. Right now, you are setting an object, not an identifier.
Unless you truly want to add the object to the new Entity $two, which you would do differently. Let us know if that's the case.

Comment: When getters and setters are generated by doctrine, argument to setOne is fixed to Two entity. If I pass integer it throws `Expected Two Got int` exception.

Comment: Then that means that `setOne()` is expecting a `Two` Entity! You probably need to re-think your design...

Comment: Please see above approved comment. it did solved my problem. thanks.